# Is it possible to customize the Bluetooth message when the alert first show up in iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth, cbperipheral

I am writing an app which uses bluetooth to send data. The first time the call is made an alert pops which says

"app name" would like to make data available to nearby bluetooth devices even when you're not using the app.

Is there a way to customize this similar to the the Location services message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription` key to store the purpose string in Info.plist to describe the reason that the app uses Bluetooth. When the system prompts the user to allow usage, this string is displayed as part of the dialog box

Comment: Can anyone explain how to use this NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription ?